# How to calculate enemy defenses in Bloodborne

Tags: bloodborne

How do people calculate the boss/enemy defenses in Bloodborne on the wikis?  For example physical/fire/bolt/arcane defenses shown here: http://bloodborne.wiki.fextralife.com/Cleric+Beast

Answer (score 2):

First, players discovered that 10 points in a resistance was equivalent to 1% damage reduction, based on tests where the players allowed enemies to damage them with no armor on, then with armors of varying defense values (as seen [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/bloodborne/comments/30uqjd/psa_how_defence_is_calculated_in_bloodborne/)). It was assumed that the same points/percentage system could be applied to enemies. People then calculated enemy resistances by fighting them, looking at the amount of damage done per attack, and comparing it to the raw damage value listed for the weapon on the inventory screen. Based on the percent damage reduction, one can then calculate the defense values using the same 10pt-to-1% formula.